# Why does the ForceCoordinateSystemIterator class next() method retype the SimpleFeature object?

Tags: java, geotools, jts

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

I have two questions

Q1: ForceCoordinateSystemIterator.class next() method why not return the original SimpleFeature but retype the SimpleFeature?

Q2: when use ForceCoordinateSystemIterator I cannot retrieve the original object to update this default geometry. what would be the best way to do that?

```java
FeatureJSON featureJSON = new FeatureJSON(new GeometryJSON(15));
InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("/arjen_data/rust/2.geojson"));
SimpleFeatureIterator simpleFeatureCollection2 = (SimpleFeatureCollection) featureJSON.readFeatureCollection(is);
try (SimpleFeatureIterator fit = simpleFeatureCollection2.features()) {
            while (fit.hasNext()) {
                // fit is ForceCoordinateSystemIterator.class
                SimpleFeature next = fit.next(); // is retype object
                Geometry defaultGeometry = (Geometry) next.getDefaultGeometry();
                Geometry intersection = defaultGeometry.difference(union);
                // update default Geometry
                next.setDefaultGeometry(intersection);
            }
}
```

i read ForceCoordinateSystemIterator.class next() method source code. I have the two questions mentioned above now.

```java
    @Override
    public SimpleFeature next() throws NoSuchElementException {
        if (reader == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Reader has already been closed");
        }

        SimpleFeature next = reader.next();
        if (builder == null) return next;

        try {
            // why retype? original object is bad?
            return SimpleFeatureBuilder.retype(next, builder);
        } catch (IllegalAttributeException eep) {
            throw (IllegalStateException)
                    new IllegalStateException(eep.getMessage()).initCause(eep);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the answer is to do with mutable and immutable objects with in the library, a `FeatureType` (schema) is immutable and the schema of an `Feature` includes information about the CRS of the `Geometry` objects so if you change the schema you must change the feature.

I suspect your life would be easier if you use the `gt-geojson-store` to get a "proper" GeoJSON datastore rather than using `gt-geojson` which is (also) unsupported but even less well supported. However, that won't let you modify the default geometry to update the collection either (I think). You probably want to [checkout this tutorial](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/tutorial/feature/csv2shp.html).

Comment: thank you sir.  `gt-geojson-store` is more convenient and faster than `gt-geojson`.

Comment: It seems that `GeoJSONWriter` cannot write the coordinate reference  system into the GeoJSON file. If indeed it's not possible, I will submit an issue on GeoTools.

Comment: GeoJSON is always in WGS84 Lon/Lat so there is no need to write a coordinate system to the file.